# Inline elements causing the text to stop wrapping? So simple?

Tags: html, css, inline, line-breaks

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/SsfpG/

I don't understand why these inline elements are causing the paragraph to stop wrapping, or, to not finish placing text before the inline element, in other words: something is causing a line-break just before the DIV set to `display:inline-block`, even if i just set it to `display:inline`. If I change the DIV's to SPAN's, then it works, but if i've set the DIV to `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` then it should work just like a SPAN.. This should be incredibly simple! ARGH!

**CSS**

```
p {
    position:relative;
}

.trigger {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative; 
}

.toolTip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

}

.triangle {
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
    Hello this is an example paragraph and I love to talk about typography
    here on somewhere in between the this and now when I see all of the
    dogs running around the streets I'm like oh my goodness puppy what are
    you doing to the cats when  

    <div class="trigger">TRIGGER TRIGGER
        <div class="toolTip">
            This part is hidden right now, this will be the tooltip, for testing
            purposes it is hidden.
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    in that one movie and i'm
    like oh wow this is insane i dont know what to even think when I see
    all of the cats gone, okay i'm gonna stop now mr person there. I'm like 
    oh my goodness puppy what are
    you doing to the cats when you see them, now they're all vanished
    since you came to town puppy
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put [block level elements inside paragraphs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). Since divs are block level elements, the browser acts as if you had written this instead:

```
<p>foo bar</p>
<div class="trigger">....
```

This is slightly different from when people discuss inline vs block when talking about CSS. The end of the paragraph element is determined while the browser is reading the HTML, before CSS is applied.

On the other hand, spans are inline elements, so that works.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your divs with inline elements will work :

```
<span class="trigger">TRIGGER TRIGGER
    <span class="toolTip">
        This part is hidden right now, this will be the tooltip, for testing
        purposes it is hidden.
        <span class="triangle"></span>
    </span>
</span>
```